# Create a new column value based on another column content from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, apply

I am trying to create a new variable called "region" based on the names of countries in Africa in another variable. I have a list of all the African countries (two shown here as an example) but I have am having encountering errors.

```
def africa(x):
  if africalist in x:
    return 'African region'
  else:
    return 'Not African region'


df['region'] = ''

df.region= df.countries.apply(africa)
```

I'm getting :

'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: Use `df['region'] = np.where(df['countries'].isin(africalist), 'African region', 'Not African region')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you see [`When should I want to use apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code).

You could use:

```
df['region'] = df['countries'].isin(africalist).map({True:'African region',
                                                     False:'Not African region'})
```

or

```
df['region'] = np.where(df['countries'].isin(africalist),
                        'African region',
                        'Not African region')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong.

The correct manner is

```
if element in list_of_elements:
```

So, changing the function `africa` results in:

```
def africa(x):
  if x in africalist:
    return 'African region'
  else:
    return 'Not African region'
```